# how to align left UIImage in objective c

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self setTitle:@"myTitle"];
   UIImageView *titleLabel = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.PNG"]];
   titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 40);
   self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
}
```

Comment: you want to place image in navigation bar....

Comment: No description of your problem? That makes your question poor quality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UIImageView *titleLabel = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nature.jpeg"]];
titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 40);
titleLabel.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRight;
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```

Comment: How about if you want it aspect fit as well?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best is to use UIImageView contentMode property.

You can use like this:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;
```

It should be ok.